# Program crashing in C++

Tags: c++

I am just starting to learn C++ and this is a program I'm writing for an exercise:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int uppercase=0, lowercase=0, digits=0, other=0, i=0;
    int character;
    char* string;
    cout << "Enter a string!\n";
    cin.getline(string, 20); 

    while(true)
        {
        character = int(*(string+i));
        if (character==0)
            {
            break;
            }
        if (character > 64 && character < 91)
            {
            uppercase++;
            }
        if (character > 96 && character < 122)
            {
            lowercase++;
            }
        if (character > 47 && character <58)
            {
            digits++;
            }
        else
            {
            other++;
            }
        i++;
        }

    cout << "Upper case " << uppercase << "\n";
    cout << "Lower case " << lowercase << "\n";
    cout << "Digits " << digits << "\n";
    cout << "Others " << other << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes after it finishes printing the results. Am I missing something really obvious here?

Side question: The variable 'other' is always increased even if it shouldn't be. Am I using the else statement wrong?

Comment: Completely beside the question, but I'd like to point your attentions to `<cctype>`, which (among others) offers the functions `std::isupper()`, `std::islower()`, and `std::isdigit()`. You are checking for ASCII codes, and you'll get the wrong results as soon as e.g. `"José"` or `"München"` enter the picture...

Comment: Yeah...checking the type using `std` methods is less prone to breakage and WTFery than expecting people to know what character `47` is.  (And more portable, too; there are still people using EBCDIC, and this code would fail horribly on them.  As well as non-English alphabets.)

Comment: Actually, he shouldn't use 8-bit encodings to begin with, but that would be pushing it a bit for beginner code. ;-)

Comment: Well...this is going over my head quickly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have not allocated memory for `string`

Try this (allocate on stack):

```
char string[256];
```

or (allocate on heap):

```
char* string = new char[256];

delete[] string;
```

**UPDATE**

Using `std` and predefined `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, etc, the code can be rewritten as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
    int uppercase=0, lowercase=0, digits=0, other=0;

    std::cout << "Enter a string!\n";

    std::string myline;
    std::getline(std::cin, myline);

    for (std::string::iterator i = myline.begin(); i != myline.end(); ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(*i))
        {
            digits++;
        }
        else if (isalpha(*i))
        {
            isupper(*i) ? uppercase++
                        : lowercase++;
        }
        else
        {
            other++;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Upper case " << uppercase << "\n";
    std::cout << "Lower case " << lowercase << "\n";
    std::cout << "Digits " << digits << "\n";
    std::cout << "Others " << other << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...or actually *using* the `std::string` class, seeing how the OP already includes the header. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. I'm having a hard time understanding pointers still. In your second solution, 'string' is still a pointer, but you initiate it as a normal variable, right? Is this equivalent to first defining an empty string and then pointing towards it?

edit concerning the string class: I am supposed to do it this way for the exercise.

Comment: `new` just allocates memory and returns the pointer to the allocated block. They both (stack/heap example) define an *undefined* string. If you want an empty string, you must explicitly empty it: `string[0] = '\0'` or `strcpy(string, "")`.

Comment: `char *string` still is a pointer, but this time with a valid memory address to an allocated piece of memory. When you don't allocate memory, your pointer will point to a random piece of memory and things can go very wrong (especially when you overwrite the content).

Answer (score 3):

The `else` statement is executed if the preceding `if` statement is false. In your case, other is increased when `(character > 47 && character <58)` is false. You probably want to be using `else-if`'s instead:

```
if(){
...
}else if{
...
}else if{
...
}else{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `char string[256]` instead of `char* string;`. I guess `getline` requires a pointer to allocated memory as input.

Comment: As Open Group's [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) states, "the application shall ensure that *lineptr is a valid argument that could be passed to the free() function. If *n is non-zero, the application shall ensure that *lineptr either points to an object of size at least *n bytes, or is a null pointer."  As the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/free.html) for `free` mentions, this means that `string` must be allocated by one of the `malloc` functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have not allocated memory for `string` and using that name is probably not a good idea:

```
char* string ;
```

and alternative declaration that would work and not shadow `std::string` since you are have `using namespace std`:

```
char str[21] ;
```

In your code if you want to use `std::string` you have to do this:

```
std::string someStringVar ;
```

since using this won't work after you declare `char *string`:

```
string someStringVar ;
```

which seems to defeat the purpose of `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `char` instead of `int` to represent character. It's because `int` is usually 4 bytes and `char` is only 1 byte (so just enough to represent one character).